# What do I do with my extra friends?

Tags: glowfish

In [Glowfish](http://www.gamezebo.com/games/glowfish) you have to rescue your friends and take them "home" to little mushroom houses. Each house requires a certain number of friends to fill it, and filing the house usually is a requirement for progressing further in a level.

I have found, however, that if I find a secret area, I usually end up with more friends than I have houses to put them in. I can end the level with these friends still following me, but does that mean I am missing out on some more secrets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Collect as many as you can and take them to the whirlpool at the end of the level.** You likely aren't missing any more secrets (whether you missed a secret area would be a level-dependent question) and the friends aren't extra if you are going for score/stars. **[To get 4 stars on a level, you seem to need to find all friends](http://forums.bigfishgames.com/posts/list/204427.page)** which is why missing an enemy kill can lead you to get only 2 stars.